# NSManagedObjectContext outside the PersistentDocument

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've created a Document Application for Mac OSX to work with CoreDataModel.

Now I'm trying to programmatically save a value in the coredata when a button is clicked.

I'm able to save a value when the app start:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
[super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

NSManagedObjcetContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSSet *session = [moc fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"Sessions" withPredicate:nil];
NSLog(@"%d", (int)[session count]);
NSManagedObject *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sessions"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[obj setValue:@"TEST" forKey:@"name"];
[obj setValue:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:112700] forKey:@"start"];
[obj setValue:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:118700] forKey:@"stop"];
}
```

but I want to save a value of a counter inside a NSObject. So I've tried to create a function in the PersistentDocument like the previous passing a value, but the count of the coredata elements is 0, so I think that is not referencing to the correct Entity.

Can anyone explain me how to do that or how this can works?

Thanks
Ale

EDIT:

I'll try to be more clear.

I've a chrono counter with START and STOP button. I want to save the value of the timer, when is stopped, in the coredata using another button SAVE. The managing of the counter is in an NSObject CounterObject.

How can I do it? Now I'm able to write in the core data only from the PersistentDocument caling a function from windowControllerDidLoadNib. I want to call a function that write in the coredata my counter value, but if I call the function in the PersistentDocument from the CounterObject the log that I've inserted show 0 elements instead of 4. So it's not correctly passed.

Here is the code:

```
// Document
#import "Document.h"
#import "NSManagedObjectContext.h"

@implementation Document

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
// Override returning the nib file name of the document
// If you need to use a subclass of NSWindowController or if your document supports multiple NSWindowControllers, you should remove this method and override -makeWindowControllers instead.
return @"Document";
}

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
[super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
[self saveTimeMOC:[NSDate dateWithString:@"11:23:34"]];
}

-(IBAction)saveTimeMOC:(NSDate *)time {

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSSet *session = [moc fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"Sessions" withPredicate:nil];
NSLog(@"%d", (int)[session count]);
NSManagedObject *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sessions"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[obj setValue:@"TEST" forKey:@"name"];
[obj setValue:time forKey:@"start"];
[obj setValue:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:118700] forKey:@"stop"];

}

+ (BOOL)autosavesInPlace
{
return YES;
}

@end

// CounterObject
#import "CounterObject.h"
#import "Document.h"

@implementation CounterObject

@synthesize contText, startButton, stopButton;

-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (IBAction)startContatore:(id)sender {
stopButton.title = @"Stop";
[stopButton setEnabled:YES];
[startButton setEnabled:NO];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(gestioneTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)stopContatore:(id)sender {
if (timer != nil) {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
if (stopButton.title != @"Reset") {
    [startButton setEnabled:YES];
    stopButton.title = @"Reset";
    startButton.title = @"Continue";
} else if (stopButton.title == @"Reset") {
    stopButton.title = @"Stop";
    [stopButton setEnabled:NO];
    startButton.title = @"Start";
    timerCont = 0;
    contText.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:00"];
}
}

- (void)gestioneTimer {
timerCont += 1;

int minutes = floor(timerCont/60);
int seconds = trunc(timerCont - minutes * 60);

contText.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds];
}

- (IBAction)saveTime:(id)sender {
Document *moc = [[Document alloc] init];
[moc saveTimeMOC:[NSDate dateWithString:@"13:45:22"]];
}
```

Comment: So far it's difficult to understand the problem you're having. Would you post the non-working code the CounterObject uses to perform the update?

Comment: I was successful to use the managedObjectContext in this way:

    NSDocumentController *controller = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
    NSPersistentDocument *document = [controller currentDocument];
    NSAssert(document, @"Document is nil.");
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [document managedObjectContext];

Now I'm receiving:

AppKit called rmdir("/private/var/folders/vc/n07nyjc902d5fh39vmjf8qqc0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A Document Being Saved By SyncaJob)"), it didn't return 0, and errno was set to 66.

Comment: I think that the problem of your code is the line : [NSDate dateWithString@"13:45:22"], se the documentation of NSDate class and the the method dateWithString

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an Object to core data, you can do this :

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
[super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

NSManagedObjcetContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];   
// But be sure that [self managedObjectContext] is the correct one; you can do this to see if   //it's not a null value : NSLog(@"%@",[self managedObjectContext]);

NSManagedObject *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sessions"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[obj setValue:@"TEST" forKey:@"name"];
[obj setValue:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:112700] forKey:@"start"];
[obj setValue:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:118700] forKey:@"stop"];
}
```

And a request for Core Data is :

```
-(voi)testRequestCoreData {
NSError *error =nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"Sessions" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm able to do that.
I can't insert in the core data a value taken from the persistentdocument view, using a SAVE button.

Comment: I think that the problem of your code is the line : [NSDate dateWithString@"13:45:22"], se the documentation of NSDate class and the the method dateWithString